# java keep objects in cpu register

Tags: java, cpu-registers

In C programming, to keep any variable in CPU resister, we use `register` specifier. Similarly to keep an object in CPU cache in java, is there an specifier in java

Comment: When you looked at the Java keywords, did you see one?

Comment: Are you aware that even in C, the `register` modifier is only a "hint" to the compiler?

Comment: @DaveNewton When I look at the Java keywords I see `goto` and `const` ;)

Answer (score 4):

No.

Java is a high-level language (certainly compared to C), so it is not possible to meddle these kind of low-level functionalities.

An additional difference with C is that Java requires a VM to run, this VM probably would require many registers, varying from time to time. So, it is unknown how many and which registers are available, so you can 'claim' one. Certainly, since each VM might behave differently (internally), so there is really way.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such control of whether an object is in cache or not in Java (or standard C AFAIK).  You generally don't need to give the `register` hint in C to place a value in a register nor does it guarantee it will be in a register.

In Java the JIT determines which variables are in registers and the CPU determines which objects (or portions of them) are in which cache (you could have three or more)

What sort of problem are you trying to solve?

BTW: If you attempt to out smart the JIT, you are more than likely to end up with code which is slower.

Comment: i want to compare the performance of a java program when some specific objects are intentionally kept in cpu cache. This reduces the cpu miss.

Comment: You can keep objects in cache by using far less data than will fit into the cache you are interested in (L1, L2, L3) accessing them repeatedly. i.e. ignoring the time taken the first time you access them. Note: registers are very different to cache. You cannot place objects in registers but you can place their values in a registers by accessing them repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Java compiler (should...) takes care of that. Modern compilers don't need such human hints anymore (most of the time...).

Answer (score 0):

Java specification doesn't provide any such feature for programmers. But still JVM can use register's or other internal memory location for optimization purpose.

But Java does provide a feature **to not cache or store value in register**.
This is done by declaring a field/data member **volatile**.